# Why does using Optional instead of Objects.isNull or obj == null give me advantage?

Tags: java, option-type, getter

I want to create method, which will use Optional functionality and return value **NodeId**. 
 
This value I should extract from **Asset** object.
In some case I already use some functionality like ifPresent, filter, flatMap. But now I want clearly understand whether can I use **Optional** with simple methods like in example below, where I need just extract value from another Object

First example supposedly not very nice but however I try to Use Optional:

```
   public Optional<NodeId> findParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
        Optional<Asset> tmpAsset = Optional.ofNullable(asset);
        if(tmpAsset.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(tmpAsset.get().getParents().iterator().next());
    }
```

In second example I try to write same things but without Optional:

```
    public NodeId tmpFindParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
        if(Objects.isNull(asset)) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return asset.getParents().iterator().next();
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure `Optional` makes a cleaner and better API than... expecting a NullPointerException. That's assuming you're using `Optional` correctly, which, IMO, you are not. I would just have `return Optional.ofNullable(asset).map(asset -> asset.getParents().iterator().next());`. That's the point of `Optional`: the caller will check if it's empty before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point to check for `null` `asset` or empty `tmpAsset` if you're going to throw `NullPointerException` in these cases.

Just write:

```
public NodeId tmpFindParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
    return asset.getParents().iterator().next();
}
```

and the `NullPointerException` will be thrown if you try to de-reference a null reference.

Now, using an `Optional` becomes useful if you don't want to throw `NullPointerException` or if `asset` is not the only reference that may be `null`.

For example, suppose that `asset.getParents()` can also be `null`, and in case either `asset` or `asset.getParents()` are null, you want to return some default value, or an empty `Optional`.

You can chain multiple `map()` calls to transform each potentially `null` reference to the next potentially `null` reference, and end with either an `Optional` (as in the example below), a default value or an exception.

```
public Optional<NodeId> findParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(asset)
                   .map(asset -> asset.getParents())
                   .map(parents -> parents.iterator().next());
}
```

In addition, it might be safer to check that `parents` is not empty before trying to obtain the first element of its `Iterator`.

Comment: Implied in this answer is that it becomes useful when you have a chain of functional elements.  You can string together several .map() functions together in a single statement and handle any null/failure/not-found condition in one place.

Comment: @AutomatedMike yes, that's what I meant in `if asset is not the only reference that may be null`, though your comment is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't exactly using `Optional` correctly in your first method, it doesn't make much sense to throw a `NullPointerException` in the method where you're returning `Optional`. See Eran's answer for proper use.

If you, however, *do* want to throw a `NullPointerException` when the input is `null`, then would use this instead:

```
public NodeId tmpFindParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(asset, "asset");
    return asset.getParents().iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using Optional you ensure the caller being aware of the returned value might be null.

Answer (score 0):

Using Optional makes the code more fluent and improves its readability.
In your case i would indeed use a Optional. For example:

```
public NodeId tmpFindParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(asset)
    .map(asset -> asset.getParents().iterator().next())
    .orElseThrow(UnsupportedOperationException::new)
}
```

Otherwise if you'd like to return the optional, just remove the orElseThrow(). For each method of getParents(), iterator() or next(), which could possibly return null, you should create a map chain not to fall into a NPE. For example:

```
public Optional<NodeId> tmpFindParentNodeIdByAsset(Asset asset) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(asset)
    .map(asset -> asset.getParents())
    .map(parents -> parents.iterator().next());
}
```